# Converting CSV to JSON using pyspark with filter and additional columns

Tags: json, join, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Given a CSV Input file with Headers:

```
"CorrelationID", "Message", "EventTimeStamp", "Flag", "RandomColumns"
12345, "Hello", "2019-06-09 04:25:15", "True", "blah"
12345, "Hello", "2019-06-09 04:25:18", "False", "blah"
45678, "Brick", "2019-06-09 04:26:23", "True", "blah"
78912, "Stone", "2019-06-09 04:29:50", "False", "blah"
```

Consider **only** those CorrelationID which has both true and false Flag. Ignore the rest of rows which don't contain both "true" and "false" value for "flag" column

`EventTimeStamp` value for True flag goes as `StartTime` and `EventTimeStamp` value for False flag goes as `EndTime`

JSON file format as Output:

```
{"CorrelationID": "12345","Message":"Hello","StartTime":"2019-06-09 04:25:15","EndTime":"2019-06-09 04:25:18"}
```

Comment: this is a good question deserve to be reopen!

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy` & inside `agg` function use `collect_set`,`first` & `last` functions. Check below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

```
df \
.withColumn(\ # casting eventtimestamp to timestamp
    "eventtimestamp", \
    F.col("eventtimestamp").cast("timestamp")\
) \
.orderBy(F.col("eventtimestamp").asc) \ # sorting eventtimestamp asc
.groupBy(F.col("correlationid"),F.col("Message")) \ # grouping records based on correlationid
.agg( \
    F.first(F.col("eventtimestamp")).cast("string").alias("StartTime"),\ # First value of eventtimestamp as StartTime
    F.last(F.col("eventtimestamp")).cast("string").alias("EndTime"), \ # Last value of eventtimestamp as End Time
    F.collect_set(F.col("flag")).alias("flag")\ # Collecting Set Of flags & Use size of this value in filter to get only records which has true and false for correlationid.
) \
.filter(F.size(F.col("flag")) === 2) \ 
.select( \
    F.to_json(\ # Adding required columns to inside struct to make json record
        F.struct(\
            F.col("CorrelationID"),\
            F.col("Message"), \
            F.col("StartTime"), \
            F.col("EndTime") \
        ).alias("json_data")\
    ) \
) \
.show(false)
```

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_data                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"CorrelationID":"12345","Message":"Hello","StartTime":"2019-06-09 04:25:15","EndTime":"2019-06-09 04:25:18"}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```